# Can't create library and link to console application

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I am writing some c# code on my linux machine using vs code. I created an initial console application and now I want to move parts of it out into a library.

So I created a multi-folder workspace and added my original directory and a new one for the library to it.

cd'd to the lib directory and ran the `dotnet new classlib` command
This created a standard lib:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

F5 still builds the original and I can cd to the lib directory and build that with no errors.

Now I move the files I want in the library and (surprisingly) the builds noted above still work. I then change the namespace in the library and add a reference from the console application to the library

`dotnet add reference ../<name>/<name>csproj`

and now no matter which I build I get the following error:

```
 Restore completed in 24.06 ms for <project name>.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error : Assets file '<path to obj>project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [<path to project>.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error : Assets file '<path to lib>/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [<path to project>.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65
```

I have run dotnet restore in both directories but I still get the error. Not sure what I have wrong here and I have seen some examples creating a sln file. Is that required for this? If not how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had an obj directory inside the bin directory hierarchy that was getting in the way of the build. I deleted all bin and obj directories and re built. No errors.